# iOS Tab in the view but not tab bar controller.

Tags: ios, swift, nstabviewcontroller

I want to have tabs like the following picture:

[image]

But I have no idea how to call this implementation. Can any body give me a hint or explanation about how to make it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can to use  UITabBar, more info here: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol)

You will have to customize it properly to make it look that way but it's pretty straight and doable. If you need help you can ask.

Comment: Thanks! I think this method is straight!

Comment: If you need any help with that, you can always ask. :)